# Auto hide Row / Column of Table if specific field exists in MySQL Database using Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mysql, django

I am working on a Django project and I am stuck in a situation where  I want to hide a row in a table if specific entity exists in column in database. I am using MYSQL database. I want auto hide row without clicking on any button or any checkbox.

page.html:

```
<table border="2">
      <tr>
        <th> ID</th>
        <th> NAME</th>
        <th> PASSWORD</th>
        <th> IP</th>
        <th>PORT</th>
      </tr>

      {% for data in Cvs_logs %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{data.id}}</td>
        <td>{{data.user}}</td>
        <td>{{data.pass}}</td>
        <td>{{data.ip}}</td>
        <td>{{data.port}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

views.py:

```
def home_view(request):
  auth = Cvs_logs.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'page.html', {'Cvs_logs': auth })
```

models.py:

```
class Cvs_logs(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField
  ip = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
  port = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
  user = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
  pass = models.CharField(max_length= 100)

  class Meta:
    db_table = "xyz"
```

The condition is if name == 'abc', then It should hide data automatically without clicking on any button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `views.py` you can use [`exclude`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) so:

```py
def home_view(request):
  auth = Cvs_logs.objects.exclude(user="abc") #here
  return render(request, 'page.html', {'Cvs_logs': auth })
```

This will not include the specific data with `user = "abc"`.